# Filler dots for Table of Contents in Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, formatting, ssrs-2008, tableofcontents

Does anyone have a slick way of adding filler dots to a table of contents page in RS?

This would not be a problem were it using proportional fonts.

e.g.

```
Monkey.........5
House..........1
Tree...........11
Underpants.....2
```

Obviously the example above sucks as the font is proportional

Comment: Forgive my ignorance - is there a built-in TOC generator in SSRS 2008, or are you constructing it yourself?

Comment: Self build! :)                
Comments must be at least 15 characters in length
Then it tells me that the 'too short' comment which I was just unable to submit means that I can't submit another comment for 15 seconds. wtf

Comment: Do you have a working TOC, or are you just researching?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible in SQL Server Reporting Services 2008.

Comment: I know you asked this some time ago but I recently came across this post while attempting to do this. I didn't find the solution posted anywhere so I figured I'd post it here. See my answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a [PlaceHolder](http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2009/04/07/the-power-of-the-placeholder/).

1. Create a Table with two columns.
2. In the column on the right put the page number.
3. In the column on the left put in your page name.
4. Place the cursor just to the right of the page name and right-click.
5. Select Create Placeholder.
6. Enter `Dots` (or whatever) for the Label.
7. Click the Function button next to the Value textbox.
8. Enter the following expression: `=StrDup(600, ".")`
9. Click OK.
10. You should end up with this: [image: Screen shot of a PlaceHolder]
11. Click off of the grid to loose focus.
12. Right-click the lower half of the left column.
13. Select Text Box Properties.
14. Under General->Sizing Options deselect Allow height to increase
15. Click OK.

*Pay no attention to the page numbers in the screen shot. I know they are wrong.*

[image: Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether this is helpful or not, but since you have control over the TOC, rather than building it as a single field, do you have the option to set it up as a table with three columns (the title, the dots, the page number)?

Whilst this would give you white-space between the title and the start of the dots, it would at least mean that the padding would be of a consistent length.

In this scenario, you could alternatively generate the dots as a patterned line inside the table cell, rather than with repeated characters.

Comment: I don't want dots of a consistent length, I want them to go all the way from the item in question all the way to the page number.

Comment: @adolf - in which case, I think you'll have to write a custom function which calculates the actual length of each line of the string given its font and point size, and pads it with the necessary number of dots to give an equal length. I'm sure I've seen examples of this kind of code, but I don't have any links to hand.